# From String to Function

Tags: c++, string, function

I'd like to know if there is a way to transform a string into a function em c++. For example if I have the string: "x+y" it'd create the function and by replacing x and y, get the value of it.

In Java there is this API https://www.objecthunter.net/exp4j/index.html, so I was wondering if there is something similar.

Comment: Look up "tokenizing", "lexing" and "parsing".

Comment: For the specific case of simple arithmetic (like e.g. `x + y`) then it's a common exercise to parse and interpret such expressions. There are solutions and examples all over the Internet if you just search a little.

Comment: That was a simple example I can have more complex expressions such as: `(x + 10) * ((log(y) * 3) + (x^32)) `

Comment: It's still relatively "simple" arithmetic. If you can handle the four basic operator (`+`, `-`, `*` and `/`) and parentheses then it's easy to add support for more advanced operators, including "function calls". The big question is if you want to implement it all yourself, or if you want to use a library for it. And if you want to be even more general and have the possibility to extend simple arithmetic to a simple scripting language with statements and such.

Answer (score 2):

There are many possible methods one could use to transform a string into a "function". Many of those involve parsing the string and building a function-like object out of it.

A lightweight and portable solution would be to use [`ExprTk`](http://www.partow.net/programming/exprtk/), a mathematical expression library developed by Arash Partow.

The main page contains various usage examples.